# SuperLearner only provides a discrete winner

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm trying to use **SuperLearner** and it doesn't matter what algorithms I add to the library, it will only provides a discrete winner with  coefficient 1. Is  there an option to prevent that from happening?

Code:

```
library(SuperLearner)

Call:  
SuperLearner(Y = msicudatatrain$IsDeceased, X = x, family = binomial(), 
SL.library = c("SL.mean", "SL.glmnet",  
    "SL.ksvm", "SL.rpart"), verbose = TRUE) 


                      Risk Coef
SL.mean_All   1.684285e-01    0
SL.glmnet_All 4.483909e-07    0
SL.ksvm_All   1.750231e-03    0
SL.rpart_All  0.000000e+00    1
```

now excluding **rpart**, same situation happens...

```
Call:  
SuperLearner(Y = msicudatatrain$IsDeceased, X = x, family = binomial(),             SL.library = c("SL.mean", "SL.glmnet",  
    "SL.ksvm"), verbose = TRUE) 


                      Risk Coef
SL.mean_All   1.683833e-01    0
SL.glmnet_All 4.482701e-07    1
SL.ksvm_All   1.989397e-03    0
```

If I try a continuous Y variable (in this case, hospital length of stays), it also give a discrete winner, which seems counter intuitive.

```
Call:  
SuperLearner(Y = msicudatatrain$ICU_LOS_Clinical, X = x, family = gaussian(), 
SL.library = c("SL.mean", "SL.glmnet",  
    "SL.ksvm", "SL.randomForest", "SL.rpart"), verbose = TRUE) 


                           Risk Coef
SL.mean_All         51.59664196    0
SL.glmnet_All        0.05281076    1
SL.ksvm_All          2.69611753    0
SL.randomForest_All  2.00135683    0
SL.rpart_All         1.38172213    0
```

What should I do?

Comment: From what package does `SuperLearner` come from? Please edit the question with the relevant `library()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

***From your result No 1:***

It shows that ***rpart*** has no risk/ error, therefore it is the clear winner and adding other learners will only increase the risk/error in the prediction.

***Similarly, from result No 2:***

It shows that ***glmnet*** has risk/ error in prediction which is magnitudes less than other two.

It seems either your classes are pretty well separated (*Risk of 0.0000 from rpart*) or there is some ***modelling error***. I would suggest you to run the *classification* models individually and check how they perform (*i.e. compare error in predictions*)

***Modelling error:*** One possibility could be forgetting to convert *factor* into *binary* features before providing it to the *SuperLearner*. SuperLearner provides a *wrapper* to use already implemented algorithms in *R*. An algorithm may or may not have a provision to directly handle factors, so you need to convert factors/ categorical features into binary features (0/1) before providing it to the *SuperLearner*.

> Refer the *official R guide* for data pre-processing and usage for *SuperLearners*: [Dataset Pre-processing for SuperLearner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuperLearner/vignettes/Guide-to-SuperLearner.html#setup-dataset)
>    It mentions: "If we had factor variables we would use model.matrix() to convert to numerics."

Comment: Thanks @Mankind_08, this is also happening when I use SuperLearner for regressions (in my example, prediction of patient length of stays). This seems odd to me.

Comment: you will have to reproduce your data and code for me or others to help better. see this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Mankind_08 . I found a modelling error and it seems to work now. Quick question: can superlearner handle categorical variables?
Thanks,

Comment: In short. SuperLearner provides a wrapper to use already implemented algorithms in R. An algorithm may or may not have a provision to directly handle factors, So you need to convert factors/ categorical features into binary features before providing it to the SuperLearner. Also if this answer help you solve the issue, then don't forget to upvote/ accept so others can also benefit from your issue.